# Group By | Relacionamento Many To Many Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, querybuilder

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Laravel 5 onde tenho as tabelas `employees`, `companies`, `exams`, `employee_exams` e seus respectivos campos conforme migration abaixo:

**:: Tabela Companies**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('razao_social', 200);
        $table->string('nome_fantasia', 200)->nullable();
        $table->char('cnpj',20)->unique();
        $table->char('cnai',20)->nullable();
        $table->char('tel',20)->nullable();
        $table->string('pessoa_contato', 200);
        $table->string('email', 200)->unique();
        $table->date('venc_programas')->nullable();
        $table->enum('tipo', ['Anual','Consultoria'])->nullable();
        $table->enum('status', ['Ativo', 'Inativo']);

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

**:: Tabela Employee**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('office_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('office_id')->references('id')->on('offices'); 
        $table->string('nome', 200);
        $table->enum('sexo', ['Masculino','Feminino']);
        $table->date('data_nascimento');
        $table->char('identidade',20)->unique()->nullable();
        $table->char('cpf',20)->nullable();
        $table->char('pis',20)->nullable();
        $table->char('ctps',20)->nullable();
        $table->char('tel_celular',20)->nullable();
        $table->char('tel_residencial',20)->nullable();
        $table->char('tel_comercial',20)->nullable();
        $table->date('data_admissao')->nullable();
        $table->date('data_aso')->nullable();
        $table->enum('status', ['Ativo', 'Inativo']);

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });


}
```

**:: Tabela Exams**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('exams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('exame', 150);
        $table->enum('renovacao', ['Semestral','Anual', 'Bienal'])->nullable();
        $table->enum('status', ['Ativo','Inativo']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**:: Tabela Employee_Exams**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employee_exams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('exam_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('exam_id')->references('id')->on('exams')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('employee_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->date('last_exam');
        $table->date('next_exam'); 
        $table->string('periodical', 100);         
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Na tabela pivo `employee_exams` armazeno os dados dos próximos exames de cada funcionário. Abaixo os relacionamentos entre os modelos:

**:: Model Company**

```
public function employees(){
    return $this->hasMany('lbo\Employee');
}

public function address_companies(){
    return $this->hasOne('lbo\Address_Company');
}
```

**:: Model Employee**

```
public function companies(){
    return $this->belongsTo('lbo\Company');
}

public function exams(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('lbo\Exam','employee_exams', 'employee_id', 'exam_id')
        ->withPivot(['last_exam','next_exam','periodical', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at']);
}
```

**:: Model Exam**

```
 public function employees(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('lbo\Employee','employee_exams', 'exam_id', 'employee_id')
        ->withPivot(['last_exam','next_exam','periodical', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at']);
}
```

**:: Model Employee_Exam**

```
public function exams(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'lbo\Employee', 'lbo\Exam'
    );
}
```

O que preciso agora é listar os exames que estão para vencer de forma agrupada, conforme esboço de View abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é de como executar a busca com `Eloquent` ou com `Query Builder e posteriormente exibir os dados para o usuário.

Fiz algo do tipo:

```
DB::table('employee_exams')            
        ->join('exams', 'employee_exams_exam_id', '=', 'exams.id')
        ->join('employees', 'employee_exams_employee_id', '=', 'employees.id')
        ->join('companies', 'companies.employee_id', '=', 'employees.id')
        ->where('companies_employee_id', $employee_id)
        ->groupBy('companies_id')            
        ->get();
```

Sem sucesso.
Preciso de ajuda no problema acima.

Comment: Esta dando erro correto? A suas relações e o retorno são muitos com groupBy então nao vai ter sucesso como voce fez.Passe na pergunta as tabelas na intergra inclusive os relacionamentos de chaves e quais campos terão nesse agrupamento...

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Virgilio. Editei a pergunta conforme solicitado. Grato